# jenkins msbuild and long delays

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I have a jenkins job that calls a windows batch command, called "build" - which just calls msbuild, zip and a few other trivial things.

It works perfectly.

Except - at the end of the batch file - once we've exited - Jenkins just pauses.  For like 20 minutes.  And then it continues running postbuild stuff as if nothing happened.

I get the feeling its trying to kill of child processes or something, but anyone got any ideas?   I currently have a 22 minute build, where 2 minutes of it are spent actually building.

Comment: Pretty hard to guess, you're going to have to look for more information yourself. I'd suggest Process Explorer (like Task manager, but has an hierarchical view and more), to figure out which processes are spawned and which remain after your msbuild/zip/... sequence. Also what happens when you call your batch command outside of Jenkins?

Comment: The problem might lie in those `other trivial things` :D Can you try turn on verbose for the commands (in the build phase where the stuck happens) and share the results? For MSBuild, try `/verbosity:detailed`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and, at least here, it was due to Jenkins job waiting for all forked processes to end, when msbuild, by default, is spawning node processes which remain active for later reuse (see nodereuse flag of msbuild, which is set to true by default).

Once nodereuse has been set to false, the waiting time at the end of jenkins job vanished. Worth a try on your side.